# The code block containing 'addError' is being executed but no error thrown during record save

Tags: debugging, before-trigger, adderror

[image: This code block gets executed as seen in debug log.]

[image: The debug log shows the System.debug message]

The code block containing 'addError' is being executed but no error thrown during record save.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is this line here:

```
objOpp = new Opportunity(id = mapOfOpportunity.get(eachKey)[0].Id);
```

You're adding an error to a record that exists only in memory. Errors will only surface when you use addError on a record that is inside of Trigger.new or Trigger.old.

You probably want to use the following code instead:

```
objOpp = mapOfOpportunity.get(eachKey)[0];
```

This assumes that mapOfOpportunity.get(eachKey)[0] returns a record that was originally sourced from Trigger.old or Trigger.new.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is in a trigger. addError AFAIK only works in triggers. If not, I'll learn something new!
Is objOpp the record passed in by the trigger? I've had problems before where I've queried for records in a trigger, and put the error on them - salesforce then completely ignores it, and upserts the records I told it failed validation.